# Not able to fetch data in format of 1E+21 from Firebird Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, firebird, linked-server

I have to migrate data from firebird database to SQL server database. For this, I have created a linked server using firebird ODBC system DSN.

There is a column of a table in firebird database, which has data type - REAL and stored data in format of **1E+21**. When I tried to fetch data of this column on SQL server via using OPENQUERY, I am getting below error:

[image]

Please me here to figure out the route cause of this error and solution of this error as well.

Comment: `There is a column of a table in firebird database, which has data type - REAL` - no, there is not. https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-floattypes.html

Comment: `data in format of 1E+21` - there is no any float point data saved in this format. What you talk about is **text string**, it is one of MANY possible ways to REPRESENT float data as a text readable by human :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation // so either your data is in some TEXT format, not "real" or anything numeric, or you mistake the real data and the textual CONVERSION your program used to convert the original binary numeric data into a text for your reading it.

Comment: This question is offtopic, because it is not about PROGRAMMING. It better be migrated to https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Arioch'The Firebird does have a `real` datatype, it is just undocumented (or at least, barely). `REAL` is an alias for `FLOAT` (although implementation-wise, `float` is floating point type with dynamic precision whose default precision is the same as `real` (but that dynamic precision of `float` is undocumented, so should be ignored). For example `create table tblwithreal (realcol real)` works just fine.

Comment: Please post the query used and the resulting error message as text. Also post table structure and sample data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's not what Arioch meant. `1E+21` is a string, not a `real`. Numbers don't have formats. Either the query converts the number to text or the field type is text

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is not correct,  `1E+21` (without quotes) in SQL is a valid floating point literal (true, it is not a "format"). In any case, I was addressing the first comment by Arioch'The that Firebired has no `REAL` data type: it has, it is an undocumented alias for `FLOAT`, which for Firebird is a 32 bit floating point type.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel again, that's not what the discussion is about. It's not about a hard-coded value in the query, it's about the *result* of that query. The result shouldn't appear as text unless the driver itself retursn everything as text and then *lies* about it in the metadata

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We are all randomly guessing on the vague comments of the OP. Personally, I think the OP is just talking about how it **looks** when he looks at the table data in his favourite query tool. In any case, I repeat that my initial comment was about the `REAL` datatype, and nothing else. So I'm not sure why you even made that initial comment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Mark is correct here, i made both points, and the first of my points probably was incorrect. Still however i think that "REAL" is most probably returned by some MS SQL tool (or handwritten scraps of paper, or whatever), not by Firebird itself, as this term is very rarely used in FB realm, it is not even documented....

Comment: Maybe trying other drivers for FB could be easier for "ole db provider msdasql"? Like DotNet provider on http://firebirdsql.org or ole db on http://ibProvider.com

Answer (score 0):

Firebird supports [CAST()](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-cast).  So ask it to CAST the column to a string or different numeric type before sending it to SQL Server.